# Find the Solution of the Exponential Equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How do I solve $5^x = 4^x+1$?
I understand how to solve for $x$ when there is one exponent, but I don't know how to solve when there is an exponent on both sides of the equation..

Comment: So how would you solve $5^x = 4$?

Comment: Check that $x=1$ is a solution and that the solution to this equation is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If $a>1$: 
$$a^x=e^{\ln{a^x}}=e^{x \ln{a}} \implies \frac{da^x}{dx}=\ln{a} \cdot a^x>0$$
Therefore  $a^x$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$ and it follows it is **injective**.

Now, Since $ \frac{5}{4}>1$, the exponential $(\frac{5}{4})^x$ is strictly increasing in $\mathbb{R}$, and consequently so is
 $$(\frac{5}{4})^x-1$$
Multiply by the strictly increasing $4^x$ to get an injective function:
$$[(\frac{5}{4})^x-1] \cdot 4^x=5^x-4^x$$
The conclusion is that there is **at most** one real $x$ that satisfies $5^x-4^x=1$, which is equivalent to:
$$5^x=4^x+1$$
This single $x$ is $1$ as Tom Bombadil pointed out.